# MSIL - Can I find the Visual Studio version that was used to build/compile a .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Is the program name that was used to build the assembly written into the assembly available anywhere in the MSIL code?

Comment: What if the assembly wasn't compiled within Visual Studio? VS is just an IDE, not a compiler. It includes one, but it doesn't necessarily mean it was used for the job.

Comment: The compiler could be csc, Roslyn, or mcs (the Mono compiler)... Visual Studio isn't really involved here.

Comment: One of the fields that `DumpBin` returns is the `Linker Version`. I don't know off the top of my head, where in the header executable that information lies, but that is probably what you want. Look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177429

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't build *anything* - Visual Studio uses [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468) to do its building<sup>1</sup>:

> Visual Studio hosts MSBuild to load and build managed projects.

In fact you can build MSIL code **without** Visual Studio by downloading Microsoft [Build Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760):

> If you don't have Visual Studio installed on your computer, you can use Build Tools 2013 to build managed applications. The Visual Basic and C# compilers are also included in this download. (In earlier versions, these tools were included in the stand-alone .NET Framework.)

**Any** compiler which satisfies the [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) standard can compile valid Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) applications - the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) C# compiler is one such example.

In other words, I don't think it's possible to obtain information about the Visual Studio version from the assembly.

Unless some additional metadata is added to the assembly by Visual Studio (I don't *think* it is), to find out what version of Visual Studio built a specific assembly, you'd have to do something like adding your own custom attributes to the assembly, which you could then use reflection to retrieve.

Obviously, you can rule out earlier versions of Visual Studio based on the .NET version that the assembly targets (e.g. Visual Studio 2012 was the first to support .NET 4.5).

This table is compiled from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) for Visual Studio:

```
.NET   Min Visual
       Studio version

1.0    2002 (7.0)
1.1    2003 (7.1)
2.0    2005 (8.0)
3.0    2005 (8.0)
3.5    2008 (9.0)
4.0    2010 (10.0)
4.5    2012 (11.0)
4.5.1  2012 (11.0)
4.5.2  2012 (11.0)
4.6    2015 (14.0)
```

<sup>1</sup> Visual Studio 2015 and above, by default, uses the new [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) compiler to compile.