# Overriding generic iterator results in BadImageFormatException when compiled with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, compiler-bug

### tl;dr:

- Overriding a generic iterator method in a constructed derived class results in a `BadImageFormatException` being thrown when compiled with Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010), regardless of .NET version (2.0, 3.0, 3.5 or 4), platform or configuration. The problem is not reproducible in Visual Studio 2012 (VS2012) and above.
- The contents of the base method (provided the source compiles) is irrelevant as it is not executed.

How can this be avoided?

---

### Description of problem

When stepping into the `in` in `Main` in the code in the [MVCE](/help/mcve) below (which would normally move the execution to the iterator method), a [`BadImageFormatException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception) is thrown when the code is compiled in Visual Studio 2010:

> [image: BadImageFormatException in VS2010]

but not in Visual Studio 2012 and above:

> [image: BadImageFormatException in VS2012]

---

### MCVE

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach ( var item in new ScrappyDoo().GetIEnumerableItems() )
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}

public class ScoobyDoo<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetIEnumerableItems()
    {
        yield return new T();
    }
}

public class ScrappyDoo : ScoobyDoo<object>
{
    public override IEnumerable<object> GetIEnumerableItems()
    {
        foreach ( var item in base.GetIEnumerableItems() )
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

---

### Things of note

- When inspecting the code with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), the compiled IL for `ScrappyDoo.GetIEnumerableItems` was the same for both the VS2010 and VS2012 binaries:

  ```cs
  .method public hidebysig virtual 
      instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<object> GetIEnumerableItems () cil managed 
  {
      // Method begins at RVA 0x244c
      // Code size 21 (0x15)
      .maxstack 2
      .locals init (
          [0] class MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo/'<GetIEnumerableItems>d__0',
          [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<object>
      )

      IL_0000: ldc.i4.s -2
      IL_0002: newobj instance void MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo/'<GetIEnumerableItems>d__0'::.ctor(int32)
      IL_0007: stloc.0
      IL_0008: ldloc.0
      IL_0009: ldarg.0
      IL_000a: stfld class MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo/'<GetIEnumerableItems>d__0'::'<>4__this'
      IL_000f: ldloc.0
      IL_0010: stloc.1
      IL_0011: br.s IL_0013

      IL_0013: ldloc.1
      IL_0014: ret
  } // end of method ScrappyDoo::GetIEnumerableItems
  ```
- Likewise, the IL for the `Main` method is the same for both VS2010 and VS2012 binaries:

  ```cs
  .method public hidebysig static 
      void Main (
          string[] args
      ) cil managed 
  {
      // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
      // Code size 69 (0x45)
      .maxstack 2
      .entrypoint
      .locals init (
          [0] object item,
          [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<object> CS$5$0000,
          [2] bool CS$4$0001
      )

      IL_0000: nop
      IL_0001: nop
      IL_0002: newobj instance void MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo::.ctor()
      IL_0007: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!0> class MysteryMachine.ScoobyDoo`1<object>::get_GetIEnumerableItems()
      IL_000c: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<object>::GetEnumerator()
      IL_0011: stloc.1
      .try
      {
          IL_0012: br.s IL_0027
          // loop start (head: IL_0027)
              IL_0014: ldloc.1
              IL_0015: callvirt instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<object>::get_Current()
              IL_001a: stloc.0
              IL_001b: ldloc.0
              IL_001c: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
              IL_0021: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
              IL_0026: nop

              IL_0027: ldloc.1
              IL_0028: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
              IL_002d: stloc.2
              IL_002e: ldloc.2
              IL_002f: brtrue.s IL_0014
          // end loop

          IL_0031: leave.s IL_0043
      } // end .try
      finally
      {
          IL_0033: ldloc.1
          IL_0034: ldnull
          IL_0035: ceq
          IL_0037: stloc.2
          IL_0038: ldloc.2
          IL_0039: brtrue.s IL_0042

          IL_003b: ldloc.1
          IL_003c: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
          IL_0041: nop

          IL_0042: endfinally
      } // end handler

      IL_0043: nop
      IL_0044: ret
  } // end of method Program::Main
  ```
- In the binaries compiled by VS2012, there is a method, `<>n__FabricatedMethod4`, which doesn't appear in VS2010:

  **VS2012**:

  [image: FabricatedMethod in Visual Studio 2012]

  **VS2010**:

  [image: FabricatedMethod in Visual Studio 2010]

  ILSpy is unable to inspect the IL for the 'broken' method in the VS2010 binaries, and encounters the following exception:

  ```cs
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Disassembler.DisassemblerHelpers.WriteTo(TypeReference type, ITextOutput writer, ILNameSyntax syntax)
     at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Disassembler.DisassemblerHelpers.WriteTo(TypeReference type, ITextOutput writer, ILNameSyntax syntax)
     at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Disassembler.ReflectionDisassembler.DisassembleMethodInternal(MethodDefinition method)
     at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TextView.DecompilerTextView.DecompileNodes(DecompilationContext context, ITextOutput textOutput)
     at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TextView.DecompilerTextView.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<DecompileAsync>b__0()
  ```

  Likewise, it is unable to view the contents of the `ScrappyDoo.GetIEnumerableItems` method as C# and shows a similar exception:

  ```cs
  ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerException: Error decompiling System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Object> MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo::GetIEnumerableItems()
   ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     // stack trace elided
  ```
- When inspecting the binaries with [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), the decompiled code for the VS2010- and VS2012-compiled code differs in the expression of the `foreach` statement:

  **VS2010**:

  ```cs
  // ISSUE: reference to a compiler-generated method
  foreach (object obj in (IEnumerable<object>) this.<>n__FabricatedMethod4())
    yield return obj;
  ```

  **VS2012** (note that the decompiled C# is the same as the source, as expected):

  ```cs
  foreach (object obj in base.GetIEnumerableItems())
    yield return obj;
  ```
- The problem is not resolved by changing the method to a property, or by adding more logic into either the base or the override.
- Changing the base method to return `IEnumerable<object>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` fixes the problem (in this contrived case), but this is not an acceptable solution.
- The problem occurs when targeting .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0, .NET 3.5, and .NET 4 in VS2010. When compiled with VS2012 and above, the target framework version is irrelevant and the code behaves as expected.
- I'm aware that [Visual Studio doesn't compile code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176159/1364007) - it just invokes [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468) (or [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)), but this problem is still an issue on a machine with VS2010 and VS2012 installed: when running the code in VS2010 the problem persists, and when running in VS2012 it doesn't. Upon setting the build output verbosity to Diagnostic, I found that both VS2010 and VS2012 are using the same MSBuild binaries at

  ```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
  ```
- The problem does not appear in VS2015 (using Roslyn to compile) - the IL is different, but I guess that's to be expected.
- I need to use Visual Studio 2010 as, where I work, we do some development on Windows XP which only supports 2010 and below.
- [PEVerify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd) gives the following output for the VS2010-compiled code:

  ```
  > peverify MysteryMachine2010.exe

  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.0
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  [IL]: Error: [MysteryMachine2010.exe : MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo::<>n__FabricatedMethod4]  [HRESULT 0x8007000B] - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

  [IL]: Error: [MysteryMachine2010.exe : MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo+<getIEnumerableItems>d__0::MoveNext]  [HRESULT 0x8007000B] - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

  2 Error(s) Verifying MysteryMachine2010.exe
  ```

  whereas for binaries compiled through VS2012 and above, the result is, as expected:

  ```
  > peverify "MysteryMachine2012.exe"

  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.0
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  All Classes and Methods in MysteryMachine2012.exe Verified.
  ```
- When running the VS2010-compiled code from the command prompt results in the following output:

  ```
  > MysteryMachine2010.exe

  Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
     at MysteryMachine.ScrappyDoo.<getIEnumerableItems>d__0.MoveNext()
     at MysteryMachine.Program.Main(String[] args) in MysteryMachine\Program.cs:line 11
  ```

---

### My actual question

Does anybody know why this is, and how it can be avoided? For my actual use case, the iterator in the base has no items in it so I made the base method `abstract` and made all the derived classes override it, but that could change at any point, rendering the <strike>hack</strike> fix useless.

Comment: Unquestionably this is a bug in the older compiler. If the compiler compiles it it should at most crash with an exception relevant to the code. A BadImageFormatException from code that the compiler output is a bug, plain and simple. That should answer "why this is". As to how you can avoid it I don't know other than to just change the code. You *could* go to Microsoft Connect and report the bug but I seriously doubt they will go back and fix these old compilers on this level, it is likely not a widespread problem. I will ponder a concrete "avoidance fix".

Comment: What if the base class does not use `yield return`, does that change anything?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - if I change the base to, say, `yield break`, `throw`, or any other compilable code, the same problem occurs. The base method is never executed.

Comment: OK, so then we know the problem is not related to the enumerator method as such, as in the compiler being tripped up by the state machine being generated. Then we're back to the overriding of the generic method with a specific method.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I suspected that Microsoft would be very unlikely to revisit a six-year-old version of Visual Studio and fix a bug which (presumably) they've explicitly fixed in a later version. I also suspect that if I have the return type of the base `List<T>` and have the override add to there list, it'd be fine. I guess that'd not be *that* terrible.

Comment: What does `peverify` say about the resulting assembly? Does this error happen when the code is run outside VS 2010 or only when it's being debugged? I'd expect `BadImageFormatException` to be thrown only when an assembly is first loaded, but in your MCVE there is no additional load going on, unless VS does something interesting in the background. In that vein, does the problem disappear if the hosting process is turned on/off in the debugging options?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I've edited the question to answer your questions: (a) PEVerify doesn't like the bad assembly. (b) The problem happens inside and outside of VS2010. (c) The problem still happens if I turn off the VS hosting process.

Comment: The fact that `peverify` gives the exception as well is seriously weird. Its whole purpose is diagnosing bad IL, which is why it shouldn't complain about bad images but explain what's wrong with them. This suggests the problem is very low level. Unfortunately I don't have VS 2010 anymore, otherwise this would be fun to look into indeed. As for avoiding the problem, since it seems to be related to the state machine VS produces, not using an iterator (in the derived class) should solve it. If the iterator is not too complicated, implementing `IEnumerable` yourself isn't hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions for working around this that don't require abandoning iterators altogether, all relying on getting VS to see past the "discrepancy" of the base and derived return types, which seems to be the source of trouble.

#### Move the iterator implementation to a method that isn't virtual/overridden

```
public override IEnumerable<object> GetIEnumerableItems()
{
    return getIEnumerableItems();
}

IEnumerable<object> getIEnumerableItems() 
{
    foreach ( var item in base.GetIEnumerableItems() )
        yield return item;
}
```

#### Move the base invocation out of the iterator, obvious way

```
public override IEnumerable<object> GetIEnumerableItems()
{
    foreach ( var item in baseItems() )
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

IEnumerable<object> baseItems() 
{
    return base.GetIEnumerableItems();
}
```

This could potentially be thwarted by inlining, but I don't think the compiler will bother (traditionally such things are left to the IL level).

#### Move the base invocation out of the iterator, involved way

```
public override IEnumerable<object> GetIEnumerableItems()
{
    return getIEnumerableItems(base.GetIEnumerableItems());
}

IEnumerable<object> getIEnumerableItems(IEnumerable<object> baseItems) 
{
    foreach ( var item in baseItems )
        yield return item;
}
```

Disclaimer: none of this is tested, for lack of a VS 2010 installation.

Comment: The first method didn't work, but the second and third did. The trouble with the second and third methods is that they require additional methods to go with *each* override of the base - in my case there are about 20 overrides of the base method. Method 2, at least, has an iterator in the actual override, which is probably preferable because it's obvious where more `yield return` statements should go.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as you provide workarounds for the problem.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: I was actually waiting for your feedback before proceeding. What version of .NET are you targeting? If at least 3.5, what might also fix the problem is `base.GetEnumerableItems().AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` had the same problem (as did `ToArray()`/`ToList()`): the combination of using `base` **and** `yield return` causes the problem, which (I think) is why 2 and 3 work but 1 doesn't.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: alright, one more thing. Could you try defining `protected static IEnumerable<U> unwrap<U>(Func<IEnumerable<U>> baseItems) { return baseItems(); }` in `ScoobyDoo` and then call `foreach ( var item in unwrap(() => base.GetIEnumerableItems()))` in `ScrappyDoo`? Even if this works I'm not sure I'd like it as a solution (hard to read, hard to understand), but it would reduce the change in derived classes to one line.

Comment: No dice. That said, the `BadImageFormatException` appears on the `return baseItems()` rather than on `in` now due to the passing of the `Func` to do the work.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: Wow. Alright, I really don't understand what the compiler's beef is and I think I don't want to know either. I'm sorry for your loss. :-) Best thing I can suggest is to define a code snippet for the boilerplate.

Comment: Mmkay, I had tried a number of workarounds without any real luck - thanks for trying. :)